# Textview in Android can only display two lines of text within RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, chat, android-relativelayout

I'm creating a chat application in android. I'm designing my chat layout using ListView on my design part i'm using RelativeLayout for chat interface, but the message text can only display two lines of text if I use 9patch bubble background and it can display three lines of text if I removed the 9patch bubble background. Below is my xml file. Why it cannot display all text? one more thing I want the chat time on the right, but it's hidden when the message text reach one or more line. Thanks for help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chat_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_history"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_section"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="02day12month"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_view_left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chat_history">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg_chatter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/msg_text_left"
            android:text="Mr. Daroath" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg_time_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg_text_left"
            android:layout_below="@+id/msg_text_left"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="10:20"
            android:textColor="#808080"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reciever_profile_pic"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg_text_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/reciever_profile_pic"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/reciever_profile_pic"
            android:text="Chat bubble is bubble in comic book that contains character's words. Some people call it speech bubble. Android app like eBuddy uses it when you are chatting with your friend."

            android:textSize="14sp" /><!-- android:background="@drawable/partner" -->
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use android:layout_width="fill_parent" in relative layout. try this

Answer (score 0):

On first sight (more problems might be there as well): you are aligninig msg_time_left with msg_text_left but that one is defined later. This normally does not work with a relativelayout. Always make sure that you use id references when you align so rather than android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg_text_left" you should use android:layout_alignRight="@id/msg_text_left". This will fail in your case as the ID is defined later on.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made some changes now it works. Anyhow, if you have any better design idea appreciated!
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chat_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_history"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_section"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="02day12month"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_wrap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/chat_history"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reciever_profile_pic"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/chat_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/msg_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10:20"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/msg_text"
                android:textColor="#808080"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/msg_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/partner"
                android:text="Chat bubble is bubble in comic book that contains character&apos;s words. Some people call it speech bubble. Android app like eBuddy uses it when you are chatting with your friend."
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/msg_time" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg_chatter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_wrap"
        android:text="Mr. Daroath" />

</RelativeLayout>
```